# Feed environment variables through bsub (Platform LSF)

Tags: unix, shell-script, environment-variables, lsf

I seem unable to pass environment variables to scripts submitted to a cluster scheduler through `bsub`. It works fine when I submits commands that use these environment variables directly, but these environment variables cannot be used in subsequent scripts. Why is that, and how can I fix it?

Here is a simple example where I tried to pass `x=1` to a script:

```
me@cluster:~[407]$ bsub -I -tty -env 'x=1' 'echo .$x.'
Info: No jobname given, set to: Job_with_no_name
Info: No output file given, set to: output_%J_%I.txt
Info: No memory limit given, set to: 512MB
Info: No runtime limit given, set to: 15min
Job <35590315> is submitted to queue <normal>.
<<Waiting for dispatch ...>>
<<Starting on linuxbmc0243>>
.1.

me@cluster:~[408]$ echo 'echo .$x.' > myechox

me@cluster:~[409]$ more myechox
echo .$x.

me@cluster:~[410]$ chmod +x myechox

me@cluster:~[411]$ bsub -I -tty -env 'x=1' myechox
Info: No jobname given, set to: Job_with_no_name
Info: No output file given, set to: output_%J_%I.txt
Info: No memory limit given, set to: 512MB
Info: No runtime limit given, set to: 15min
Job <35590318> is submitted to queue <normal>.
<<Waiting for dispatch ...>>
<<Starting on linuxbmc1279>>
..

me@cluster:~[412]$ bsub -I -tty -env 'x=1' 'export x;myechox'
Info: No jobname given, set to: Job_with_no_name
Info: No output file given, set to: output_%J_%I.txt
Info: No memory limit given, set to: 512MB
Info: No runtime limit given, set to: 15min
Job <35590340> is submitted to queue <normal>.
<<Waiting for dispatch ...>>
<<Starting on linuxbmc1045>>
..
```

**Update**: This works:

```
me@cluster:~[456]$ bsub -I -tty -env 'x=1' 'export x=$x;myechox'
Info: No jobname given, set to: Job_with_no_name
Info: No output file given, set to: output_%J_%I.txt
Info: No memory limit given, set to: 512MB
Info: No runtime limit given, set to: 15min
Job <35609253> is submitted to queue <normal>.
<<Waiting for dispatch ...>>
<<Starting on linuxbmc0975>>
.1.
```

In the meantime, I have also found out that `bsub` prefers to be used with `bsub < scriptfile` rather than `bsub scriptfile`; this seems to be required to enable parsing of embedded options (using `#BSUB`), and it also explains why variables are only set locally (because no sub-script has to be called).

However, now I have also tried this, which, surprisingly, does not work:

```
me@cluster:~[457]$ bsub -I -tty -env 'x=1' < myechox
Info: No jobname given, set to: Job_with_no_name
Info: No output file given, set to: output_%J_%I.txt
Info: No memory limit given, set to: 512MB
Info: No runtime limit given, set to: 15min
Job <35609459> is submitted to queue <normal>.
<<Waiting for dispatch ...>>
<<Starting on linuxbmc1140>>
..
```

**Update 2**: I have tried `export`ing `x` first, which has the same effect as using `-env 'x=1'`:

```
me@cluster:~[458]$ export x=1

me@cluster:~[460]$ bsub -I -tty 'echo .$x.'
Info: No jobname given, set to: Job_with_no_name
Info: No output file given, set to: output_%J_%I.txt
Info: No memory limit given, set to: 512MB
Info: No runtime limit given, set to: 15min
Job <35610151> is submitted to queue <normal>.
<<Waiting for dispatch ...>>
<<Starting on linuxbmc1140>>
.1.

me@cluster:~[459]$ bsub -I -tty < myechox
Info: No jobname given, set to: Job_with_no_name
Info: No output file given, set to: output_%J_%I.txt
Info: No memory limit given, set to: 512MB
Info: No runtime limit given, set to: 15min
Job <35609990> is submitted to queue <normal>.
<<Waiting for dispatch ...>>
<<Starting on linuxbmc1140>>
..
```

**Update 3**: This, again, works, which I consider an answer to my question:

```
me@cluster:~[571]$ (echo export x=$x && cat myechox) | bsub -I -tty
Info: No jobname given, set to: Job_with_no_name
Info: No output file given, set to: output_%J_%I.txt
Info: No memory limit given, set to: 512MB
Info: No runtime limit given, set to: 15min
Job <35641024> is submitted to queue <normal>.
<<Waiting for dispatch ...>>
<<Starting on linuxbmc1045>>
.1.
```

Comment: Have you try to set: export x=1 and then exec the script?

Comment: @RomeoNinov: even better: I have tried `export x=$x;myechox`, and this works, too. I wonder if this is expected to be done like that...

Comment: Bers, yes, if you export variable in shell it is populated to all subshell instances you start after the export (which is IMHO what you need :) )

Comment: @RomeoNinov Okay, I see. In the meantime, I have found out that `bsub` prefers to be used with `bsub < scriptfile` rather than `bsub scriptfile`; this seems to be required to enable parsing of embedded options (using `#BSUB`). So while I need to my question, the original question still stands unfortunately ;)